# Why is my first batch of cookies out of the oven too flat?

Tags: baking, cookies, rising

Every time I make cookies, the first batch out of the oven is a bit too thin and flat. Subsequent batches are as expected. What could be causing this?

Comment: Do you chill your cookie dough?

Comment: I do not chill the dough; it usually doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: And yet your cookies come out thin! Try it and the oven temperature tip and you'll be golden.

Comment: Ha ha, fair enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It may be that your oven is not up to temperature before your first batch goes in. If it's not hot enough your cookies will have more time to melt and flatten before they cook. Try giving the oven 10 more minute preheating time before putting your first batch in.

Comment: Some ovens now have a preheat timer, usually about 10 minutes.  In my expreience that is not long enough for consistent baking, although you have to get to know your own oven.   30 minutes is usually a better time.  Ovens bake mostly be radiant (infrared) transfer of energy from the walls, floor and ceiling to the baked goods.  For this reason, the walls, floor, and ceiling must be up to temperature before you start baking for consistent results.   (For some applications like braising, this is not as critical.)

Comment: Adding to @SAJ14SAJ , even if your oven's air temperature is at the desired level if the inside of your oven may not be fully heat-soaked. When you open the oven door the temperature drops, and then the oven has to heat the air back up. If the oven material isn't up to temperature then that won't happen very quickly, hence flat cookies.

Comment: This makes sense. I should probably bake with my pizza stone in the oven, too.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, I use mine as it really helps keep the temperature stable, just remember it needs at least half an hour to get up to temperature!

Comment: @KatieK I got surprised muffins rised really much more in my woodfired oven than in the electric one. It's like a baking stone of 10 cm (4 in) thickness. So, it makes sense to use a pizza stone in an electric conventional home oven.

Comment: I have a gas oven. Wow, you baked in a wood fired oven? That's old school.